# Treating wildcards at standard characters in an INDEX(MATCH(COUNTIF())) formula

Tags: excel, match, wildcard, sumifs

I am using the formula:

`=(INDEX($A$2:$A$300, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($B$1:B1, $A$2:$A$300), 0))`

This takes a list of values from column A and reproduces it in column B to show each value only once, i.e. if a value is duplicated, it gets skipped.

For the most part it is working exactly as I hoped, however, some of the values in column A contain the wildcard character '?'.

Is it possible to get this formula to treat the '?' as just a standard character? Ideally I would like to include this rule in the formula itself rather than having to do a 'find and replace' with '~?'. Is this at all possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your formula to:

```
=(INDEX($A$2:$A$300,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1:B1,SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$300,"?","~?")),0)))
```

confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

This replaces the `?` in the criteria array with `~?` within your formula.

Comment: That's great! Thanks very much, it works perfectly. If in the future I need to ignore a second character, e.g. '~', would it be possible to use something like SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$300, {"?", "~"}, {"~?", "~~"})?

Comment: You have to nest your `SUBSTITUTE` functions to perform multiple replacements.  It does not work with array constants in the manner you would want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "escape" those characters. This is done the same as when searching in Excel, by prepending them with the tilde character: ~

So this searches for the question mark:

```
=MATCH("~?",A1:A10,0)
```